# System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'Item'

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, treeview

I'm attempting to control a datagridview from a TreeView control and also converting from VB.Net to C# and Have encountered an error on these two lines :

```
sRef = lWADataBaseDataSet.orderTBL.Rows[I].Item[0];
sOrder = lWADataBaseDataSet.orderTBL.Rows[I].Item[1];
```

The code from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHyESZfaxxE) is (containing my database information):

```
if treeView1.SelectedNode is nothing then
orderTBLDataGridView.DataSource = nothing
exit sub
end if
if treeview1.SelectedNod.Name = "root" then
orderTBLDataGridView.DataSource = nothing
exit sub
end if

dim sRef as string
sRef = treeview1.SelectedNode.name
orderTBLDataGridView.DataSource = lWADataBaseDataSet.orderTBL("id=" & id);
```

All code :

```
public void ordersForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'lWADataBaseDataSet.orderTBL' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.orderTBLTableAdapter.Fill(this.lWADataBaseDataSet.orderTBL);
            string sRef = null;
            string sOrder = null;
            int I = 0;
            for (I = 0; (I
             <= (lWADataBaseDataSet.orderTBL.Count - 1)); I++)
            {

                sRef = lWADataBaseDataSet.orderTBL.Rows[I].Item[0];
                sOrder = lWADataBaseDataSet.orderTBL.Rows[I].Item[1];

                treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(sRef, sOrder);
            }
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((treeView1.SelectedNode == null)) {
                orderTBLDataGridView.DataSource = null;
    return;
}
if ((treeView1.SelectedNode.Name == "root")) {
    orderTBLDataGridView.DataSource = null;
    return;
}
string sRef;
sRef = treeView1.SelectedNode.Name;
orderTBLDataGridView.DataSource = lWADataBaseDataSet.orderTBL.Select(("Reference=" + sRef));

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Field extension method:

```
sRef = lWADataBaseDataSet.orderTBL.Rows[I].Field<string>(0);
sOrder = lWADataBaseDataSet.orderTBL.Rows[I].Field<string>(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call the items as such:

```
sRef = lWADataBaseDataSet.orderTBL.Rows[I][0];
sOrder = lWADataBaseDataSet.orderTBL.Rows[I][1];
```

No need to declare Items as in VB becasuse in C# DataRow.Items is an indexer itself.